# Most pleasant way to ask users to switch to a new package (remove actual app and install new one)

Tags: java, android, installation, uninstallation

I have 5 apps adapted to different countries. I could in the last week make a all-in-one app including the 7 countries (in 5 apps). So I would like my users to all switch to the international version that is much easier for me to maintain.

What is the strategy I should adopt to offer users the most confortable user experience in switching to the new app ? I aim to get a 100 % transfer rate.. :)

Users will have to erase their actual app and install the new one.

Thanks in advance, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Hi well what i do is a having a webservice that knows if i hava new version if theres a new version he ask a message and open a dialog with a webview the answer is html so there for i can send every kind of message. In your case could be a link to a the new app. the new app in the first versions could check if the other is installed and uninstall the old one :D these is just an opinion sorry my english

Comment: you can use these for check updates http://www.androidsnippets.com/check-for-updates-once-a-day

Comment: Thanks for this library but I want users to swtich to an entirely different package, not to upgrade to a new version of the same package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well the first thing that comes to my mind is: because you can actually redirect to your app in the market you can post an update with a dialog showing up at startup explaining why they should download the new app and have it redirect (on ok and on canceled and on every click basically) to the market to download your new app. this however will block the usage of your app if they don't install the new one so there might be people frowning upon this move..

also what you can do is actually remove the previous app after instalation of the new one and keep that transition smoother for the users.

Because android doesnt allow apps with the same package names, you cant really merge things into one app.

i am also curious to see what others might suggest.

Hope this helps.
Don't forget to vote :D.

Comment: With the addition of the in-app billing, I'm also interested in this. Currently, my idea is exactly what DArkO suggested (a kind dialog). Right now, it's still better for me to keep different apps because the billing API does not support 1.5, and I have around 17% of users still stuck with 1.5 (that also is holding me back on a other issues). Anyway, just saying here that I agree with the answer.

Comment: @DArkO thx, I wait to see if there are other alternatives. And how do you remove the actual app after the new one is installed ?

Comment: Well if you know this there are apps like the uninstaler app that does the same thing as going through settings applications for removing apps. so package managment (installing/uninstalling apps) is possible. and here is a link on how to do it. http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98

Comment: so this means that you can also do the instalation yourself but i would still go through the market. it keeps track of statistics(downloads,installs etc) which is what you don't get when going around it with a manual install. plus its kinda more appealing for the user because he will have the option to approve the process.

Comment: Indeed, I don't recommend using the installer and uninstaller package proposed by @DArkO. This package relies on some hidden classes of the android SDK and it's 1) difficult to compile and 2) not standard enough to be integrated to an app deployed on the market. So I will just ask users to do a manual update, unfortunately I can't make it more automatic... :(

Comment: well apps like the uninstaller are quite popular on the market and using this thing. and apart from that i only mentioned using that just to try to uninstall the previous app after the new one was installed. so maybe try to run a service at first launch of the new app to uninstall the old one and catch any exceptions in the process so even if it fails you at least tried to make the process smoother. in android you can't guarantee for something to be 100% functional. that comes with all the different devices out there..

Comment: and about installation i wouldn't think twice about going through a manual update from the market. there are too much benefits to using that (as i said you get statistics, the user gets update notifications and the best of it all i think doing it through the market makes the app look more secure and appealing for the users).